# Uninstall my current application by itself OR after exiting

Tags: android, android-activity, uninstallation

I need to **uninstall** my application which I am **running** on my device **currently** or **after certain seconds of exiting** the application. I know uninstall current running by itself is breaking of android life cycle. But its necessary to do for **project necessity** and **privacy**. I know its easy to delete other applications from my current application by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("com.example.steve"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But how I can uninstall self application and exit or uninstall the app after certain time of exiting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way.  Of course this pops up a dialog, because the decision to uninstall or not **is up to the user to decide, not you**.  You do not have the authority to uninstall your application, however you could presumably revoke some kind of authorization which you have made your code depend on in order to be functional.

Comment: If it works for others, why wouldn't it work for your app from a timer? 
**But**, why?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having it automatically un-install itself, you could have a console open and run the following code which removes it completely.

```
adb shell pm uninstall your.package.name.here
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But that's the plan to uninstall the app itself.